# How to avoid \n in JSON output

Tags: json, powershell

Trying to convert object to string in PowerShell and the output gives `\n` after each line and if I delete `$result = $result | Out-String` it throws

> Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Value'. Specified method is not supported.

```bsh
$result = @(  )

$result = $result | Out-String

foreach ($point in $j) {
    $seconds = [long]$point.Time
    $point.Time = Get-EpochDate $seconds

    $result += "`n" + $point.Time
}
```

and the output is

```json
[
    {
        "key": "Time",
        "value": "\"\\n07/30/2019 17:34:16\\n07/29/2019 15:23:20\\n07/29/2019 13:54:05\""
    }
]
```

Expecting

```json
[
    {
        "key": "Time",
        "value": "07/30/2019 17:34:1,
                  07/29/2019 15:23:20,
                   07/29/2019 13:54:05"
    }
]
```

Comment: Are you expecting `"value"` to be an array or a multi-line string?

Comment: either one is fine. But expecting an array

Comment: Ok, then it wouldn't be all contained in quotes, it would be more like `"07/30/2019 17:34:01","07/29/2019 15:24:20","07/29/2019 13:54:05"` except that each item would be on its own line. To accomplish that you would need to delete the line `$result = $result | Out-String`

Comment: If I delete ```$result = $result | Out-String``` this  error pops up ```Cannot convert 'System.Object[]' to the type 'System.String' required by parameter 'Value'. Specified method is not supported```

Comment: Where does that come up? Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57280876/edit) your question to include the code that is throwing that error.

Comment: Beckend tool where I'm writing the code

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to send an array to an API that doesn't accept arrays. Or maybe you just need to convert the epoch date to a string. Try adding `|out-string` to your `Get-EpochDate` lines.

Comment: The code you posted would not produce the output (or error) you posted. Please create a [mcve] that would allow us to reproduce the problem you're facing.

Comment: Are you sure that you can have multiple date/time for the `value` field? Have you tried an hard-coded string? Have you looked at each string using a debugger? It look like your string in encoded twice.